# how to access hadoop slaves which have the same IP address but different port numbers

Tags: docker, hadoop, ssh

My question is, I'm wondering if it's possible Hadoop can do ssh access with a different port number(not 22) for slaves when it makes a Hadoop cluster.

Detail)
I tried to make Hadoop cluster with two slaves.
The master node is on my local computer, but the other nodes are on my AWS ec2 as Docker containers.

local : master node
AWS EC2(33.162.168.105) : first Hadoop container as slave #1, second Hadoop container as slave #2
(btw, this ip addr is fake.)

The first slave container opened 1111 port number for 22 with **-p 1111:22** option,
The second slave container opened 1112 port number for 22 with **-p 1112:22** option
so that remote computer can do ssh access into slave#1 with 1111 port number.

Actually, when I tried to do ssh access into slave#1 with 1111 port number from my local computer terminal, it worked well!

The problem is Hadoop ssh connection as slaves to make cluster.
I'm using Hadoop 3.1.1 version so I had to put slaves ip into /etc/hadoop/workers like,

33.162.168.105:1111

But after run start-all.sh, I showed errors.

```
server@9130cf720e0f:/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop# start-all.sh
Starting namenodes on [master]    
Starting datanodes
33.162.168.105:1111: ssh: Could not resolve hostname 33.162.168.105:1111: Name or service not known
Starting secondary namenodes [9130cf720e0f]
Starting resourcemanager
Starting nodemanagers
33.162.168.105:1111: ssh: Could not resolve hostname 33.162.168.105:1111: Name or service not known
```

I know I can't add ":1111" at the end of the ip addr.
So I really wanna know if it's possible Hadoop can do ssh access with a different port number(1111 in this case) for slaves when it makes a Hadoop cluster.
If you know how to, help me, please.

Thank you for your reading and help in advance.